# Asking a negative question

Tags: grammar, questions

What should I say and why?

1) Why is not this tree long?

2) Why is this tree not long?

3) Why this tree is not long? (I almost exclude this possibility)

Comment: what do you think? You have to add more information as to why you think a sentence is correct or not.

Comment: Actually it is a grammar issue. There is a precise way to ask about something. In my question, I am sure that either the first or the second sentence is correct. If you are asking me what I mean by the question itself, I mean that I expected the tree's longest to be more, so I am asking about the reason.

Comment: @user105719 please don't use the comment boxes to write answers.  This breaks the up and down voting model of the site.  You should use comments to ask for details or suggest improvements.